# Object recognition vuforia

Tags: ios, objective-c, vuforia, object-recognition

I am using "vuforia" SDK for Object recognition in iOS.I am using sample code give by vuforia and able to recognise object using "ObjectReco" part.

```
- (void)renderFrameWithState:(const Vuforia::State &)state projectMatrix:(Vuforia::Matrix44F &)projectionMatrix{
[self setFramebuffer];
// Clear colour and depth buffers
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

// Render video background
[sampleAppRenderer renderVideoBackground];

glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);

glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

for (int i = 0; i < state.getNumTrackableResults(); ++i) {
    // Get the trackable
    const Vuforia::TrackableResult* result = state.getTrackableResult(i);
    const Vuforia::Trackable& trackable = result->getTrackable();

    if (! result->isOfType(Vuforia::ObjectTargetResult::getClassType())) {
        continue;
    }

    NSLog(@"@>@ ObjectTarget found!");

    const Vuforia::ObjectTarget& objectTarget = (const Vuforia::ObjectTarget&) trackable;

    Vuforia::Vec3F objectSize = objectTarget.getSize();

    //const Vuforia::Trackable& trackable = result->getTrackable();
    Vuforia::Matrix44F modelViewMatrix = Vuforia::Tool::convertPose2GLMatrix(result->getPose());

    // OpenGL 2
    Vuforia::Matrix44F modelViewProjection;

    SampleApplicationUtils::translatePoseMatrix(objectSize.data[0]/2,
                                                objectSize.data[1]/2,
                                                objectSize.data[2]/2,
                                                &modelViewMatrix.data[0]);
    SampleApplicationUtils::scalePoseMatrix(objectSize.data[0]/2,
                                            objectSize.data[1]/2,
                                            objectSize.data[2]/2,
                                            &modelViewMatrix.data[0]);

    SampleApplicationUtils::multiplyMatrix(&projectionMatrix.data[0], &modelViewMatrix.data[0], &modelViewProjection.data[0]);

    glUseProgram(shaderProgramID);

    glVertexAttribPointer(vertexHandle, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (const GLvoid*)cubeVertices);
    glVertexAttribPointer(normalHandle, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (const GLvoid*)cubeNormals);
    glVertexAttribPointer(textureCoordHandle, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (const GLvoid*)cubeTexCoords);

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(vertexHandle);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(normalHandle);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(textureCoordHandle);

    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, augmentationTexture[0].textureID);
    glUniformMatrix4fv(mvpMatrixHandle, 1, GL_FALSE, (const GLfloat*)&modelViewProjection.data[0]);
    glUniform1i(texSampler2DHandle, 0 /*GL_TEXTURE0*/);

    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, NUM_CUBE_INDEX, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, (const GLvoid*)cubeIndices);

    glDisableVertexAttribArray(vertexHandle);
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(normalHandle);
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(textureCoordHandle);

    SampleApplicationUtils::checkGlError("EAGLView renderFrameVuforia");

}

glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glDisable(GL_BLEND);
glDisable(GL_CULL_FACE);
[self presentFramebuffer];}
```

I am able to get object at "NSLog(@"@>@ ObjectTarget found!");" now I want to replace this object(image) with another object(image) how I can do this ?

Answer (score 0):

please go to Vuforia official website. They have a series of instructions on how to change the preset target image to your own ones. I think you need to upload your own target image onto Vurforia in the first place, and then they will show you the instructions to proceed to next step.
hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

If I got you true:
in Vuforia we did replace by putting our new object in the same hierarchy of the target object, and it will be appear once Vuforia recognize the target!
you can Cover the target (in the Editor) by your object.